# Erro em utilização do google Sheets

Tags: google

Um usuário do Google Sheets fez uma chamada com um erro na utilização do Google Sheets. Ele trabalhava com uma planilha compartilhada de outra pessoa e tinha permissão total sobre o documento. Como ela não tinha mais necessidade de compartilhar as informações com essa outra pessoa, ele fez a copia da planilha no drive dele e excluiu a planilha compartilhada. Voltando ao trabalho na planilha ela tentou copiar os valores de um Sheets completamente para utilizar num relatorio em outra planilha e apareceu o seguinte erro na tela dela

[image: Erro na planilha]

Gostaria de saber porque aconteceu esse erro sendo que a planilha é de propriedade dela. A resolução que foi apresentada para resolver o problema de autorização foi copiar os valores aos poucos ao invés de copiar tudo de uma vez e funcionou.